# Django: Retrieve values from m2m-field on save

Tags: django, django-models

I am having a problem whit retrieving the selected fields in a many to many field when saving from the admin interface.

This is a simplified version of my model.

```
class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length = 100)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Sites)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        // Do something with the value of sites
        for site in self.sites.all():
            print site

        super(Template, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This should print all the selected sites when saving in the admin interface. However, this actually prints all the sites that were selected before saving!

Image I have a Template with name 'foo' and sites ['a', 'b']. When I edit it in the admin interface and deselect site 'b', I want it to print ['a']. However, the output is ['a', 'b'], e.g. the old value.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `save` will commit the changes, so you probably want to iterate over the sites afterwards, like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Template, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    for site in self.sites.all():
        print site
```

If you specifically want to perform an action pre or post save, then have a look at [how signals work in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).